# BouncyCastle undefined length ASN1

Tags: c#, xamarin, mono, portable-class-library, x509

I try to get a X509Certificate2 from a BountyCastle X509Certificate and a PKCS12. I use the following code:

```
 certificate = new X509Certificate2(rawData, password, storageFlags);
```

I generate the rawData, like the following:

```
using (MemoryStream pfxData = new MemoryStream())
{
   X509CertificateEntry[] chain = new X509CertificateEntry[1];

   chain[0] = new X509CertificateEntry(x509);
   pkcsStore.SetKeyEntry(applicationName, new AsymmetricKeyEntry(subjectKeyPair.Private), chain);
   pkcsStore.Save(pfxData, passcode.ToCharArray(), random);
   var rawData = pfx.ToArray();
}
```

The problem is, that I get the following exception:

[image]

After some days of researching, I figured out, that the problem is based on the Mono implementation of ASN1. This implementation doesn't allow "Undefined length encoding". If I use the code on Windows it works great.

**My question**

Is there any way, to convert the pfxData stream to a valid ASN1 structure?

I have tried it with the following code:

```
Asn1InputStream asn1InputStream = new Asn1InputStream(pfxData);
var asn1Object = asn1InputStream.ReadObject();

MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
new Asn1OutputStream((Stream)memoryStream).WriteObject(asn1Object);
var asn1ByteArray = memoryStream.ToArray();

certificate = new X509Certificate2(asn1ByteArray);
```

But with this code, I get the following exception:

> "Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.\nParameter name: startIndex"

I use Xamarin PCL with .NET Standard 1.3 and I can only use the "Portable.BouncyCastle" Nuget package.

**UPDATE Exception Stack Trace (Converting BER to DER):**

```
05-28 15:19:54.895 D/Mono    ( 3808): Assembly Ref addref Mono.Security[0x9b4fe080] -> System[0xac8de400]: 17
05-28 15:19:54.957 I/mono-stdout( 3808): System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: Unable to decode certificate. ---> System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: Input data cannot be coded as a valid certificate. ---> System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: Unable to decode certificate. ---> System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: Input data cannot be coded as a valid certificate. ---> System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
Parameter name: startIndex
  at System.String.IndexOf (System.String value, System.Int32 startIndex, System.Int32 count, System.StringComparison comparisonType) [0x0002a] in <d18287e1d683419a8ec3216fd78947b9>:0 
  at System.String.IndexOf (System.String value, System.Int32 startIndex, System.StringComparison comparisonType) [0x00009] in <d18287e1d683419a8ec3216fd78947b9>:0 
  at System.String.IndexOf (System.String value, System.Int32 startIndex) [0x00000] in <d18287e1d683419a8ec3216fd78947b9>:0 
  at Mono.Security.X509.X509Certificate.PEM (System.String type, System.Byte[] data) [0x00030] in <2940be14d5a1446694e2193e9029b558>:0 
  at Mono.Security.X509.X509Certificate..ctor (System.Byte[] data) [0x00014] in <2940be14d5a1446694e2193e9029b558>:0 
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at Mono.Security.X509.X509Certificate..ctor (System.Byte[] data) [0x0002f] in <2940be14d5a1446694e2193e9029b558>:0 
05-28 15:19:54.958 I/mono-stdout( 3808): Parameter name: startIndex
  at System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2ImplMono.Import (System.Byte[] rawData, System.String password, System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509KeyStorageFlags keyStorageFlags) [0x0000b] in <1a27f8ea09e3480db932cbde0eaedfb2>:0 
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2ImplMono.Import (System.Byte[] rawData, System.String password, System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509KeyStorageFlags keyStorageFlags) [0x00031] in <1a27f8ea09e3480db932cbde0eaedfb2>:0 
  at System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Helper2.Import (System.Byte[] rawData, System.String password, System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509KeyStorageFlags keyStorageFlags, System.Boolean disableProvider) [0x00020] in <1a27f8ea09e3480db932cbde0eaedfb2>:0 
  at System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2.Import (System.Byte[] rawData, System.String password, System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509KeyStorageFlags keyStorageFlags) [0x00000] in <1a27f8ea09e3480db932cbde0eaedfb2>:0 
  at System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2..ctor (System.Byte[] rawData) [0x00011] in <1a27f8ea09e3480db932cbde0eaedfb2>:0 
05-28 15:19:54.958 I/mono-stdout( 3808):   at System.String.IndexOf (System.String value, System.Int32 startIndex, System.Int32 count, System.StringComparison comparisonType) [0x0002a] in <d18287e1d683419a8ec3216fd78947b9>:0 
  at APP.Models.Services.ACommunicationService.CreateCertificate (System.String storeType, System.String storePath, System.String password, System.String applicationUri, System.String applicationName, System.String subjectName, System.Collections.Generic.IList`1[T] domainNames, System.UInt16 keySize, System.DateTime startTime, System.UInt16 lifetimeInMonths, System.UInt16 hashSizeInBits, System.Boolean isCA, System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2 issuerCAKeyCert) [0x003b5] in C:\projects\APP - Kopie\APP_XamarinApplication\APP\APP\APP\Models\Services\ACommunicationService.cs:517 
05-28 15:19:54.958 I/mono-stdout( 3808):   at System.String.IndexOf (System.String value, System.Int32 startIndex, System.StringComparison comparisonType) [0x00009] in <d18287e1d683419a8ec3216fd78947b9>:0 
  at APP.Models.Services.ACommunicationService.CreateCertificate (System.String storeType, System.String storePath, System.String applicationUri, System.String applicationName, System.String subjectName, System.Collections.Generic.IList`1[T] serverDomainNames, System.UInt16 keySize, System.UInt16 lifetimeInMonths, System.UInt16 hashSizeInBits) [0x00001] in C:\projects\APP - Kopie\APP_XamarinApplication\APP\APP\APP\Models\Services\ACommunicationService.cs:318 
  at APP.Models.Services.ACommunicationService+<ACommunicationServiceAsync>d__18.MoveNext () [0x00972] in C:\projects\APP - Kopie\APP_XamarinApplication\APP\APP\APP\Models\Services\ACommunicationService.cs:214 
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
05-28 15:19:54.959 I/mono-stdout( 3808):   at System.String.IndexOf (System.String value, System.Int32 startIndex) [0x00000] in <d18287e1d683419a8ec3216fd78947b9>:0 
  at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional (System.Boolean includeTaskCanceledExceptions) [0x00011] in <d18287e1d683419a8ec3216fd78947b9>:0 
  at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait (System.Int32 millisecondsTimeout, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) [0x00043] in <d18287e1d683419a8ec3216fd78947b9>:0 
  at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait () [0x00000] in <d18287e1d683419a8ec3216fd78947b9>:0 
  at APP.Models.Services.ACommunicationService..ctor (PCLStorage.IFolder rootFolder) [0x00010] in C:\projects\APP - Kopie\APP_XamarinApplication\APP\APP\APP\Models\Services\ACommunicationService.cs:46 
05-28 15:19:54.959 I/mono-stdout( 3808):   at Mono.Security.X509.X509Certificate.PEM (System.String type, System.Byte[] data) [0x00030] in <2940be14d5a1446694e2193e9029b558>:0 
05-28 15:19:54.959 I/mono-stdout( 3808):   at Mono.Security.X509.X509Certificate..ctor (System.Byte[] data) [0x00014] in <2940be14d5a1446694e2193e9029b558>:0 
05-28 15:19:54.959 I/mono-stdout( 3808):    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
05-28 15:19:54.959 I/mono-stdout( 3808):   at Mono.Security.X509.X509Certificate..ctor (System.Byte[] data) [0x0002f] in <2940be14d5a1446694e2193e9029b558>:0 
05-28 15:19:54.959 I/mono-stdout( 3808):   at System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2ImplMono.Import (System.Byte[] rawData, System.String password, System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509KeyStorageFlags keyStorageFlags) [0x0000b] in <1a27f8ea09e3480db932cbde0eaedfb2>:0 
---> (Inner Exception #0) System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: Unable to decode certificate. ---> System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: Input data cannot be coded as a valid certificate. ---> System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
05-28 15:19:54.961 I/mono-stdout( 3808):    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
05-28 15:19:54.961 I/mono-stdout( 3808):   at System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2ImplMono.Import (System.Byte[] rawData, System.String password, System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509KeyStorageFlags keyStorageFlags) [0x00031] in <1a27f8ea09e3480db932cbde0eaedfb2>:0 
05-28 15:19:54.961 I/mono-stdout( 3808):   at System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Helper2.Import (System.Byte[] rawData, System.String password, System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509KeyStorageFlags keyStorageFlags, System.Boolean disableProvider) [0x00020] in <1a27f8ea09e3480db932cbde0eaedfb2>:0 
05-28 15:19:54.962 I/mono-stdout( 3808):   at System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2.Import (System.Byte[] rawData, System.String password, System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509KeyStorageFlags keyStorageFlags) [0x00000] in <1a27f8ea09e3480db932cbde0eaedfb2>:0 
05-28 15:19:54.962 I/mono-stdout( 3808):   at System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2..ctor (System.Byte[] rawData) [0x00011] in <1a27f8ea09e3480db932cbde0eaedfb2>:0 
Parameter name: startIndex
05-28 15:19:54.963 I/mono-stdout( 3808):   at APP.Models.Services.ACommunicationService.CreateCertificate (System.String storeType, System.String storePath, System.String password, System.String applicationUri, System.String applicationName, System.String subjectName, System.Collections.Generic.IList`1[T] domainNames, System.UInt16 keySize, System.DateTime startTime, System.UInt16 lifetimeInMonths, System.UInt16 hashSizeInBits, System.Boolean isCA, System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2 issuerCAKeyCert) [0x003b5] in C:\projects\APP - Kopie\APP_XamarinApplication\APP\APP\APP\Models\Services\ACommunicationService.cs:517 
05-28 15:19:54.963 I/mono-stdout( 3808):   at APP.Models.Services.ACommunicationService.CreateCertificate (System.String storeType, System.String storePath, System.String applicationUri, System.String applicationName, System.String subjectName, System.Collections.Generic.IList`1[T] serverDomainNames, System.UInt16 keySize, System.UInt16 lifetimeInMonths, System.UInt16 hashSizeInBits) [0x00001] in C:\projects\APP - Kopie\APP_XamarinApplication\APP\APP\APP\Models\Services\ACommunicationService.cs:318 
05-28 15:19:54.964 I/mono-stdout( 3808):   at APP.Models.Services.ACommunicationService+<ACommunicationServiceAsync>d__18.MoveNext () [0x00972] in C:\projects\APP - Kopie\APP_XamarinApplication\APP\APP\APP\Models\Services\ACommunicationService.cs:214 
05-28 15:19:54.964 I/mono-stdout( 3808):    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
05-28 15:19:54.965 I/mono-stdout( 3808):   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional (System.Boolean includeTaskCanceledExceptions) [0x00011] in <d18287e1d683419a8ec3216fd78947b9>:0 
05-28 15:19:54.965 I/mono-stdout( 3808):   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait (System.Int32 millisecondsTimeout, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) [0x00043] in <d18287e1d683419a8ec3216fd78947b9>:0 
05-28 15:19:54.965 I/mono-stdout( 3808):   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait () [0x00000] in <d18287e1d683419a8ec3216fd78947b9>:0 
  at System.String.IndexOf (System.String value, System.Int32 startIndex, System.Int32 count, System.StringComparison comparisonType) [0x0002a] in <d18287e1d683419a8ec3216fd78947b9>:0 
05-28 15:19:54.965 I/mono-stdout( 3808):   at APP.Models.Services.ACommunicationService..ctor (PCLStorage.IFolder rootFolder) [0x00010] in C:\projects\APP - Kopie\APP_XamarinApplication\APP\APP\APP\Models\Services\ACommunicationService.cs:46 
05-28 15:19:54.966 I/mono-stdout( 3808): ---> (Inner Exception #0) System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: Unable to decode certificate. ---> System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: Input data cannot be coded as a valid certificate. ---> System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
05-28 15:19:54.966 I/mono-stdout( 3808): Parameter name: startIndex
05-28 15:19:54.967 I/mono-stdout( 3808):   at System.String.IndexOf (System.String value, System.Int32 startIndex, System.Int32 count, System.StringComparison comparisonType) [0x0002a] in <d18287e1d683419a8ec3216fd78947b9>:0 
  at System.String.IndexOf (System.String value, System.Int32 startIndex, System.StringComparison comparisonType) [0x00009] in <d18287e1d683419a8ec3216fd78947b9>:0 
  at System.String.IndexOf (System.String value, System.Int32 startIndex) [0x00000] in <d18287e1d683419a8ec3216fd78947b9>:0 
  at Mono.Security.X509.X509Certificate.PEM (System.String type, System.Byte[] data) [0x00030] in <2940be14d5a1446694e2193e9029b558>:0 
  at Mono.Security.X509.X509Certificate..ctor (System.Byte[] data) [0x00014] in <2940be14d5a1446694e2193e9029b558>:0 
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at Mono.Security.X509.X509Certificate..ctor (System.Byte[] data) [0x0002f] in <2940be14d5a1446694e2193e9029b558>:0 
  at System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2ImplMono.Import (System.Byte[] rawData, System.String password, System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509KeyStorageFlags keyStorageFlags) [0x0000b] in <1a27f8ea09e3480db932cbde0eaedfb2>:0 
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2ImplMono.Import (System.Byte[] rawData, System.String password, System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certif
icates.X509KeyStorageFlags keyStorageFlags) [0x00031] in <1a27f8ea09e3480db932cbde0eaedfb2>:0 
  at System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Helper2.Import (System.Byte[] rawData, System.String password, System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509KeyStorageFlags keyStorageFlags, System.Boolean disableProvider) [0x00020] in <1a27f8ea09e3480db932cbde0eaedfb2>:0 
  at System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2.Import (System.Byte[] rawData, System.String password, System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509KeyStorageFlags keyStorageFlags) [0x00000] in <1a27f8ea09e3480db932cbde0eaedfb2>:0 
  at System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2..ctor (System.Byte[] rawData) [0x00011] in <1a27f8ea09e3480db932cbde0eaedfb2>:0 
  at APP.Models.Services.ACommunicationService.CreateCertificate (System.String storeType, System.String storePath, System.String password, System.String applicationUri, System.String applicationName, System.String subjectName, System.Collections.Generic.IList`1[T] domainNames, System.UInt16 keySize, System.DateTime startTime, 
System.UInt16 lifetimeInMonths, System.UInt16 hashSizeInBits, System.Boolean isCA, System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2 issuerCAKeyCert) [0x003b5] in C:\projects\APP - Kopie\APP_XamarinApplication\APP\APP\APP\Models\Services\ACommunicationService.cs:517 
  at APP.Models.Services.ACommunicationService.CreateCertificate (System.String storeType, System.String storePath, System.String applicationUri, System.String applicationName, System.String subjectName, System.Collections.Generic.IList`1[T] serverDomainNames, System.UInt16 keySize, System.UInt16 lifetimeInMonths, System.UInt16 hashSizeInBits) [0x00001] in C:\projects\APP - Kopie\APP_XamarinApplication\APP\APP\APP\Models\Services\ACommunicationService.cs:318 
  at APP.Models.Services.ACommunicationService+<ACommunicationServiceAsync>d__18.MoveNext () [0x00972] in C:\projects\APP - Kopie\APP_XamarinApplication\APP\APP\APP\Models\Services\ACommunicationService.cs:214 <---
05-28 15:19:54.968 I/mono-stdout( 3808):   at System.String.IndexOf (System.String value, System.Int32 startIndex, System.StringComparison comparisonType) [0x00009] in <d18287e1d683419a8ec3216fd78947b9>:0 
05-28 15:19:54.969 I/mono-stdout( 3808):   at System.String.IndexOf (System.String value, System.Int32 startIndex) [0x00000] in <d18287e1d683419a8ec3216fd78947b9>:0 
05-28 15:19:54.969 I/mono-stdout( 3808):   at Mono.Security.X509.X509Certificate.PEM (System.String type, System.Byte[] data) [0x00030] in <2940be14d5a1446694e2193e9029b558>:0 
05-28 15:19:54.969 I/mono-stdout( 3808):   at Mono.Security.X509.X509Certificate..ctor (System.Byte[] data) [0x00014] in <2940be14d5a1446694e2193e9029b558>:0 
05-28 15:19:54.969 I/mono-stdout( 3808):    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
05-28 15:19:54.969 I/mono-stdout( 3808):   at Mono.Security.X509.X509Certificate..ctor (System.Byte[] data) [0x0002f] in <2940be14d5a1446694e2193e9029b558>:0 
05-28 15:19:54.969 I/mono-stdout( 3808):   at System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2ImplMono.Import (System.Byte[] rawData, System.String password, System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509KeyStorageFlags keyStorageFlags) [0x0000b] in <1a27f8ea09e3480db932cbde0eaedfb2>:0 
05-28 15:19:54.969 I/mono-stdout( 3808):    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
05-28 15:19:54.969 I/mono-stdout( 3808):   at System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2ImplMono.Import (System.Byte[] rawData, System.String password, System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509KeyStorageFlags keyStorageFlags) [0x00031] in <1a27f8ea09e3480db932cbde0eaedfb2>:0 
05-28 15:19:54.970 I/mono-stdout( 3808):   at System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Helper2.Import (System.Byte[] rawData, System.String password, System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509KeyStorageFlags keyStorageFlags, System.Boolean disableProvider) [0x00020] in <1a27f8ea09e3480db932cbde0eaedfb2>:0 
05-28 15:19:54.970 I/mono-stdout( 3808):   at System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2.Import (System.Byte[] rawData, System.String password, System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509KeyStorageFlags keyStorageFlags) [0x00000] in <1a27f8ea09e3480db932cbde0eaedfb2>:0 
05-28 15:19:54.970 I/mono-stdout( 3808):   at System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2..ctor (System.Byte[] rawData) [0x00011] in <1a27f8ea09e3480db932cbde0eaedfb2>:0 
05-28 15:19:54.970 I/mono-stdout( 3808):   at APP.Models.Services.ACommunicationService.CreateCertificate (System.String storeType, System.String storePath, System.String password, System.String applicationUri, System.String applicationName, System.String subjectName, System.Collections.Generic.IList`1[T] domainNames, System.UInt16 keySize, System.DateTime startTime, System.UInt16 lifetimeInMonths, System.UInt16 hashSizeInBits, System.Boolean isCA, System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2 issuerCAKeyCert) [0x003b5] in C:\projects\APP - Kopie\APP_XamarinApplication\APP\APP\APP\Models\Services\ACommunicationService.cs:517 
05-28 15:19:54.971 I/mono-stdout( 3808):   at APP.Models.Services.ACommunicationService.CreateCertificate (System.String storeType, System.String storePath, System.String applicationUri, System.String applicationName, System.String subjectName, System.Collections.Generic.IList`1[T] serverDomainNames, System.UInt16 keySize, System.UInt16 lifetimeInMonths, System.UInt16 hashSizeInBits) [0x00001] in C:\projects\APP - Kopie\APP_XamarinApplication\APP\APP\APP\Models\Services\ACommunicationService.cs:318 
05-28 15:19:54.971 I/mono-stdout( 3808):   at APP.Models.Services.ACommunicationService+<ACommunicationServiceAsync>d__18.MoveNext () [0x00972] in C:\projects\APP - Kopie\APP_XamarinApplication\APP\APP\APP\Models\Services\ACommunicationService.cs:214 <---
```

**EDIT:** I have posted the same question in BouncyCastle GitHub: [BouncyCastle GitHub](https://github.com/bcgit/bc-csharp/issues)

**EDIT 2:** I have tested to save the PKCS and create a X509Certificate2 with string constructor, like the following:

```
var pkcsPath = pkcsStorePath + "/pkcs.p12";
File.WriteAllBytes(pkcsPath, pfxData.ToArray());

// Exception is thrown on this line (Undefined length):
certificate = new X509Certificate2(pkcsPath, string.Empty);
```

**Edit 3:** I have found the method `var util = Pkcs12Utilities.ConvertToDefiniteLength(pfxData.ToArray(), certPassword.ToCharArray());` in the BouncyCastle library and if I use this method right before the `File.WriteAllBytes(pkcsPath, util);` line, the exception "Undefined length encoding." is gone. But now, I get the following exception:

```
06-01 21:05:54.903 I/mono-stdout(31001): System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: Input data cannot be coded as a valid certificate. ---> System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: Input data cannot be coded as a valid certificate.
System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: Input data cannot be coded as a valid certificate. ---> System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: Input data cannot be coded as a valid certificate.
  at Mono.Security.X509.X509Certificate.Parse (System.Byte[] data) [0x0003b] in <2940be14d5a1446694e2193e9029b558>:0 
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at Mono.Security.X509.X509Certificate.Parse (System.Byte[] data) [0x00322] in <2940be14d5a1446694e2193e9029b558>:0 
  at Mono.Security.X509.X509Certificate..ctor (System.Byte[] data) [0x00030] in <2940be14d5a1446694e2193e9029b558>:0 
06-01 21:05:54.905 I/mono-stdout(31001):   at Mono.Security.X509.X509Certificate.Parse (System.Byte[] data) [0x0003b] in <2940be14d5a1446694e2193e9029b558>:0 
  at System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2ImplMono.Import (System.Byte[] rawData, System.String password, System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509KeyStorageFlags keyStorageFlags) [0x00041] in <1a27f8ea09e3480db932cbde0eaedfb2>:0 
  at System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Helper2.Import (System.Byte[] rawData, System.String password, System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509KeyStorageFlags keyStorageFlags, System.Boolean disableProvider) [0x00020] in <1a27f8ea09e3480db932cbde0eaedfb2>:0 
  at System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2.Import (System.Byte[] rawData, System.String password, System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509KeyStorageFlags keyStorageFlags) [0x00000] in <1a27f8ea09e3480db932cbde0eaedfb2>:0 
  at System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2..ctor (System.Byte[] rawData, System.String password) [0x00011] in <1a27f8ea09e3480db932cbde0eaedfb2>:0 
  at Pkcs12TestProject.MyClass.CreateCertific
ate (System.String storeType, System.String storePath, System.String password, System.String applicationUri, System.String applicationName, System.String subjectName, System.Collections.Generic.IList`1[T] domainNames, System.UInt16 keySize, System.DateTime startTime, System.UInt16 lifetimeInMonths, System.UInt16 hashSizeInBits, System.Boolean isCA, System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2 issuerCAKeyCert, System.String pkcsStorePath) [0x00377] in C:\OneDrive\VS\Pkcs12TestProject\Pkcs12TestProject\Pkcs12TestProject\MyClass.cs:223 
06-01 21:05:54.906 I/mono-stdout(31001):    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
06-01 21:05:54.906 I/mono-stdout(31001):   at Mono.Security.X509.X509Certificate.Parse (System.Byte[] data) [0x00322] in <2940be14d5a1446694e2193e9029b558>:0 
06-01 21:05:54.906 I/mono-stdout(31001):   at Mono.Security.X509.X509Certificate..ctor (System.Byte[] data) [0x00030] in <2940be14d5a1446694e2193e9029b558>:0 
06-01 21:05:54.906 I/mono-stdout(31001):   at System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2ImplMono.Import (System.Byte[] rawData, System.String password, System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509KeyStorageFlags keyStorageFlags) [0x00041] in <1a27f8ea09e3480db932cbde0eaedfb2>:0 
06-01 21:05:54.906 I/mono-stdout(31001):   at System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Helper2.Import (System.Byte[] rawData, System.String password, System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509KeyStorageFlags keyStorageFlags, System.Boolean disableProvider) [0x00020] in <1a27f8ea09e3480db932cbde0eaedfb2>:0 
06-01 21:05:54.906 I/mono-stdout(31001):   at System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2.Import (System.Byte[] rawData, System.String password, System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509KeyStorageFlags keyStorageFlags) [0x00000] in <1a27f8ea09e3480db932cbde0eaedfb2>:0 
06-01 21:05:54.907 I/mono-stdout(31001):   at System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2..ctor (System.Byte[] rawData, System.String password) [0x00011] in <1a27f8ea09e3480db932cbde0eaedfb2>:0 
06-01 21:05:54.907 I/mono-stdout(31001):   at Pkcs12TestProject.MyClass.CreateCertificate (System.String storeType, System.String storePath, System.String password, System.String applicationUri, System.String applicationName, System.String subjectName, System.Collections.Generic.IList`1[T] domainNames, System.UInt16 keySize, System.DateTime startTime, System.UInt16 lifetimeInMonths, System.UInt16 hashSizeInBits, System.Boolean isCA, System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2 issuerCAKeyCert, System.String pkcsStorePath) [0x00377] in C:\OneDrive\VS\Pkcs12TestProject\Pkcs12TestProject\Pkcs12TestProject\MyClass.cs:223
```

**Edit 4:** If I use the X509 certificate from BountyCastle as rawdata in the X509Certificate2 method, it works great! But it is without the private key..

Comment: Indefinite length is not allowed in DER (DER is more restricted subset of BER).

Comment: Thank you, but how can I use your hint in c#?

Comment: Do you have a DotNetUtilities class from Bouncy Castle available? It can convert bouncy cert to .Net cert, than you can use .Net cert to create X509Certificate2

Comment: I can't use DotNetUtilities. But if I try to create a X509Certificate2 from a BC X509Certificate, it works great. Only if I add the PKCS stream, which contains the private key and the X509certificate, I get this error.

Comment: If it were possible, to use the DotNetUtilities, then I could create a .Net cert and add it to the Mono.Security PKCS12. Because if I use the Mono PKCS12, it works great. But the problem is, that I have a BC X509 cert.

Comment: Can you share the full exception stack trace from after attempting to convert the BER to DER?

Comment: Of course, I have added the full exception stack trace to the question.

Comment: @bartonjs: I have set a bounty for my question, to motivate you. ;)

Comment: I'm trying to replicate your environment... it's going slowly :). I'm wondering if you ended up with Base64, or something. It also seems like Mono doesn't load PFX through the byte[] ctor which doesn't take a password.

Comment: @bartonjs There seems to be a workaround that you can use the ctor with byte[] and string.empty (byte[], string) if you don't have a password which would work better than the ctor with only byte[].

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found some bugreports on your problem with possible workarounds outlined. I don't have an appropriate environment to test this myself - sorry. But from the history it looks like it hasn't really been resolved:

1. [Bugreport](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1660):

This explicitly states problems with BouncyCastle just like you experience. Sebastian Pouliot posts a sample code in [comment3](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1660#c3) that he thinks can be used (or parts of it) to work around the problem using mono.security.dll. I don't know if your usecase allows to use it. It is shipped with MonoDroid.
He goes into details in this [comment](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1660#c5) and has the example code linked on github: https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/master/mcs/tools/security/makecert.cs

2. There is also someone else who posted a problem with this. BouncyCastle is not explicitly mentioned: http://lists.ximian.com/pipermail/mono-bugs/2010-October/104908.html

His **workaround** at the end of post:
[Once you have the correct PKCS#12] Quote:

> Write the byte[] PKCS#12 into a temporary file and load it with string
>   constructor.

---

**Update on source provided in comments**

Hope my system worked correctly as it took hours to get it running. But then I got the following working.

> The solution is to change the StoreBuilder to UseDEREncoding to true

**Small bugfix up front**
Finding: You put in a string.empty as password but protected the cert with a password. I think this is not correct. If I put in the password I get the first error again CryptographicException Certificate cannot be coded to valid certificate.

So first I changed this:

```
certificate = new X509Certificate2(pkcsPath, string.Empty);
```

to

```
certificate = new X509Certificate2(pkcsPath, certPassword);
```

**Fix**
And now I don't know if this is what you want but after changing it I didn't get an exception but a certificate object.

The complete changes of the "using memory stream" block finally looked like this:

```
using (MemoryStream pfxData = new MemoryStream())
{
    // **Change 1**: The DER Encoding is enabled on the
    // store builder
    Pkcs12StoreBuilder builder = new Pkcs12StoreBuilder();
    builder.SetUseDerEncoding(true);
    Pkcs12Store pkcsStore = builder.Build();
    // change - end

    X509CertificateEntry[] chain = new X509CertificateEntry[1];
    string certPassword = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
    chain[0] = new X509CertificateEntry(x509);
    pkcsStore.SetKeyEntry(applicationName, new AsymmetricKeyEntry(subjectKeyPair.Private), chain);
    pkcsStore.Save(pfxData, certPassword.ToCharArray(), random);

    var pkcsPath = pkcsStorePath + "/pkcs.p12";

    File.WriteAllBytes(pkcsPath, pfxData.ToArray());

    // **Change 2**: Use certificate password
    certificate = new X509Certificate2(pkcsPath, certPassword);
    // **Change 3**: Possible to use array instead of filename
    // works as well. Just uncomment
    //certificate = new X509Certificate2(pfxData.ToArray(), certPassword);

}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. 1. I have tried to use some code of the makecert.cs, but I can't compile it. The problem is, that the X509CertificateBuilder has some properties which are not available. For example: X509CertificateBuilder.SubjectPublicKey (Error: Reference to type 'AsymmetricAlgorithm' claims it is defined in 'mscorlib', but it could not be found) 2. It doesn't work for me. Perhaps, the PKCS#12 isn't correct!? I updated my question with the code to save the file and I have created a test project:  http://1drv.ms/u/s!Aq2x4hOwAC2nl5J9ZzkHXyB-2-DObw

Comment: @SeanStayn Looks like I need a Mac for that? and a VS2017? Can't get it to run as I don't have both of that. But one question from code reading: right before the exception line (215) you create a certPassword but you use string.empty in the ctor? Wouldn't that need to be the certPassword (your newGuid)?

Comment: You don't need a mac, but you need the android sdk, xamarin, and so on.. You are right, in normal I enter the certPassword to that, but for trying, I changed it to string.Empty.

Comment: @SeanStayn Updated my answer. Let me know if you cannot use this solution for some reason or its not working.

Comment: You should change your name to hero! Thank you! :) It works perfectly!!!!!! :) The keything was your first change. You should make a hint in your answer, that 'builder.SetUseDerEncoding(true);' was the problem. :)

Comment: Now if only `SetUseDerEncoding(true)` was the default it'd have saved a lot of trouble.  I was finally about to have the time load up the solution and see what was what.  Nice find, Uwe.

Answer (score 0):

Part of the problem seems to be that Mono's X509Certificate2 byte[] constructors don't behave the same as .NET Framework's X509Certificate2 byte[] constructors.

Browsing through the [mono source](https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/522d4bedf065cee278f9b7355ed60f1358d0dcb0/mcs/class/System/System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates/X509Certificate2ImplMono.cs#L470-L484) it looks like `X509Certificate2(byte[])` will try to load as a X.509 (individual) certificate, then as a PFX with a `null` (vs empty) password.

What has me the most confused about your callstack, and I was hoping to reproduce, is that it tried a PEM decode... which should only happen when the first byte isn't 0x30 ([per the source](https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/522d4bedf065cee278f9b7355ed60f1358d0dcb0/mcs/class/Mono.Security/Mono.Security.X509/X509Certificate.cs#L217-L231)), but 0x30 should be the first byte of the PFX as well.  (Then there's their mishandling of not finding `-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----` resulting in the `ArgumentOutOfRangeException` which sent me down a bad path. Oh, well.)

The .NET Framework implementation of `new X509Certificate2(byte[])` is more flexible:

- X.509 DER
- X.509 PEM
- PFX null password
- PFX empty password
- PKCS#7 SignedCms signer certificate
- AuthentiCode signer certificate

(So Mono only tries half the things .NET Framework / .NET Core does)

Based on comments it seems like you are using a PFX with an empty password, so changing your post-DER normalization call from

```
new X509Certificate2(asn1ByteArray)
```

to

```
new X509Certificate2(asn1ByteArray, string.Empty)
```

should solve this particular aspect of the problem.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'm using the password parameter with a real password and I've tried it with string.Empty, but the exception is still existing. I have created a test project with the code. The code is in the PCL in the MyClass.cs: https://1drv.ms/u/s!Aq2x4hOwAC2nl5J9ZzkHXyB-2-DObw